# Swift: convert const char ** output parameter to String

Tags: ios, c, swift, pointers, char

I'm interacting with a C++ library (with the header in C) which uses `const char **` as an output parameter.

After executing a method in that library, the value I need is written in that variable, for example:

```
CustomMethod(const char **output)

CustomMethod(&output)

// Using the `output` here
```

Normally, in Swift it's possible to pass just a standard Swift `String`  as a parameter and it will be transparently transformed into the `const char *` ([Interacting with C Pointers - Swift Blog](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=6)).

For example, I already use the following construct a lot with the same library:

```
// C
BasicMethod(const char *input)

// Swift
let string = "test"
BasicMethod(string)
```

However, when it comes to working with `const char **`, I couldn't just pass a pointer to the Swift `String`, as I'd expected:

```
// C
CustomMethod(const char **output)

// Swift
var output: String?
CustomMethod(&output)
```

Getting an error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<String?>' to
> expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafePointer?>'
> (aka 'UnsafeMutablePointer<Optional<UnsafePointer>>')

The only way I could make it work is by manipulating the pointers directly:

```
// C
CustomMethod(const char **output)

// Swift
var output: UnsafePointer<CChar>?
CustomMethod(&output)
let stringValue = String(cString: json)
```

**Is there any way to use the automatic Swift string to `const char **` conversion, or does it only work with `const char *`?**

Comment: To answer the question from the last paragraph - no, it's not possible to get automatic conversion, you'll have to write some Swift pointer code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bridged C function expects a mutable pointer to a `CChar` pointer, so you'll need to provide one, there's no automatic bridging here.

```swift
var characters: UnsafePointer<CChar>?
withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &characters) {
    CustomMethod($0)
}

if let characters = characters {
    let receivedString = String(cString: characters)
    print(receivedString)
}
```

Same code, but in a more FP manner:

```swift
var characters: UnsafePointer<CChar>?
withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &characters, CustomMethod)

var receivedString = characters.map(String.init)
print(receivedString)
```

Comment: Thanks for your clarification! It seems that I've missed `withUnsafeMutablePointer` method, which is important according to the developer documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2429788-withunsafemutablepointer